# How to create a texture made out of multiple color layers

Tags: modeling, materials

I wanted to ask if you know how to make multiple layers on a sphere. I wanted to make a sort of jawbreaker Ball that if Opened or cut would reveal different color layers. and if there is a way to make it a sort of material that would adapt to any model. if you have seen something like that please send me a YT link or something I haven't found something along these lines myself.
thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
This is using a boolean difference modifier on the sphere. The texture nodes in Blender are 3D which means the sphere gradient texture contains information about the inside of the object the material is applied to.